# как добавить слэш в конец URL адреса

Tags: javascript, php, html5, .htaccess, url

не получается добавить слеш в конце url.

сайт сейчас на поддомене, может в этом проблема. 
+ еще не получается убрать папку (/templates/) из url, чтобы домен выглядел так. 
http://develop.vverh.studio/nastroyka-kontekstnoy-reklamy/

сейчас так ! 
http://develop.vverh.studio/templates/nastroyka-kontekstnoy-reklamy

Comment: А какие варианты использовали,  покажите код?

Comment: 1. RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]

Comment: 2, RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.html)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.jpg)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-site.ru/$1/ [L,R=301]

Comment: короче все что Яндекс поиск показывал. ))) не какой вариант не работает

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Советую просмотреть урок о том, как скрывали путь в yii2

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

Это, чтобы в yii2 скрыть  папку `web` из урла

Comment: не работает. ошибка 500

Comment: Просто скопировать не выйдет, так как надо под себя подгонять. Этот пример скрывает папку web и должен находится в .htaccess файле в корне (там где точка входа в приложение). Заметьте, что там перенаправление идет на `/web/index.php`, которого у вас нет. Вам надо сделать перенаправление в тот файл, которой является единой точкой входа